# Return a dynamic property from a target in another project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

How can i "return" a dynamic property that gets set in a target in another project?

***a.msbuildproj:***

```
...
<Target Name="A">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PropA>a</PropA>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
...
```

***b.msbuildproj:***

```
...
<Target Name="A">
    <MSBuild 
        Project="a.msbuildproj"
        Target="A"/>
    <Message Text="$(PropA)"/>
</Target>
...
```

`b` calls target `A` in `a`, `A` sets property `PropA`, i need the value of `PropA` in `b`.

Background: I have setup an (appx) packaging project to package a desktop application and an application project. In the application project, i have a target that generates a version number i also want to use/have access to in the packaging project.

I know you can't "return" a property from a target in another project, but how would i solve this with msbuild?

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible to return a property from a target in another project.

Is it feasible to print the value of PropA in a and call a's Target A in b?

***a.msbuildproj***

```
<Target Name="A">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PropA>a</PropA>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="$(PropA)"/>
</Target>
```

***b.msbuildproj***

```
<Target Name="A">
  <MSBuild 
    Projects="a.msbuildproj"
    Targets="A"/>
</Target>
```